# How to define a part of a directory path as a variable for further use using R?

Tags: r, variables, path, directory

I have a little question regarding the script that I would like to write using R. The problem is the following:

I have quite a long script, in which folders are generated and the working directory is set differently several times. And as I'm not the only one, who will be using this script, I would like to write it in a way that everybody only has to change the directory, which is defined as `XXX` once. This means that USER_1 can use the code as shown below, whereas USER_2 just has to change the definition of `XXX`.

I tried to do this in the following way:

```
XXX <- "C:/users/USER_1/Desktop"

setwd(XXX)

path_Folder1 <- "XXX"
new_Folder1 <- "MainFolder/"
dir.create(file.path(dirname(path_Folder1), new_Folder1))

path_Subfolder1 <- "XXX/MainFolder/."
new_Subfolder <- "Subfolder/"
dir.create(file.path(dirname(path_Subfolder1), new_Subfolder))
```

Setting the working directory as well as the creation of the first folder works perfectly fine. However, for the subfolder I get this error message:

```
Warning message:
In dir.create(file.path(dirname(path_Subfolder1), new_Subfolder)) :
  cannot create dir 'XXX\MainFolder\Subfolder', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Did I miss to add something to this code? Or how would it be possible solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help already in advance!

Comment: `"XXX/MainFolder/."`<-- not an answer, but what is that stray dot doing at the end?  Have you checked that `XXX/MainFolder` in fact already exists?  If not, then obviously the second creation call would fail.

Comment: With this command I would like to create a subfolder within the main folder. Therefore, I just wanted to expand the directory of XXX by adding `/MainFolder/.`. I thought that this would then result in the string `"C:/users/USER_1/Desktop/MainFolder/."`, in which the subfolder should have been created. And yes, most likely, this doesn't work like this but I don't know how I could change in a similar way that I could just extend the directory shown in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
# Let users change this variable
personal_dir <- "C:/users/USER_1/Desktop"

# Create main folder
main_folder <- "Mainfolder"
main_folder_path <- file.path(personal_dir, main_folder)
dir.create(main_folder_path)

# Create sub folder
sub_folder <- "Subfolder"
sub_folder_path <- file.path(personal_dir, main_folder, sub_folder)
dir.create(sub_folder_path)
```

I think the reason your code didn't work correctly is that you had the `XXX` between quotes, i.e. it was processed as a literal string instead of as a pointer to a saved value.

Comment: Does it work also to save documents using this approach with `file.path(...)`?

Comment: You can concatenate all parts of the path as you wish, so you can also add a filename and extension at the end of the path and then use the resulting string to save a file.